# Perform select and multiple inserts as transaction using C Connector?

Tags: mysql, c, transactions

I am using MySQL. I have a select statement followed by a number of insert statement done using the C Connector. I would like to know how to put them all under one transaction and finally commit then.

I have gone through the MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual and [C API Function Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-function-overview.html) it have this function `mysql_commit()`? I must have a start transaction (how to set this is it by just turning off the `autocommit()`) and finally only commit right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand, there is no mysql_starttransaction() or something similar; so you're stuck with something like:

```
mysql_autocommit(conn, 0); 
//Do stuff here
mysql_commit(conn); //...or mysql_rollback(conn);
```

I would rather use the "query" method for all these calls:

```
mysql_query(conn, "START TRANSACTION");
//Do stuff here
mysql_query(conn, "COMMIT"); //...or mysql_query(conn, "ROLLBACK");
```

Also [see this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html#trx).

Comment: @robll looks like transaction also cant help me. My issue here is that every second I am running a select statement and based on the resultset I run insert statements. The issue here I keep getting the error as Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now